# Prevent users from changing DataGrid's SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF 4.0 application and I am using the WPF DataGrid.  What I want is to use navigation buttons on my view to change the SelectedItem the DataGrid, rather than letting the user change the SelectedItem by clicking on the DataGrid.  I am using an ICollectionView in my ViewModel as the ItemsSource for my DataGrid.  Here is what I have so far:

NextCommand (ViewModel):

```
DefaultView.MoveCurrentToNext();  // DefaultView is an ICollectionView
SelectedItem = DefaultView.CurrentItem as MyProperty;
```

DataGrid (View):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultView}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

The navigation buttons work great... however, I do not want to allow the user to click on the DataGrid to change the SelectedItem.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  I've played around with the DataGrid_SelectionChanged event, but the problem is that the binding on the SelectedItem updates the ViewModel before this event even fires.  I would prefer that the SelectedItem does not get changed twice (once when the user clicks, and twice when it is set back to the original).  I am ok with using the Code behind if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to disable it through a custom DataGrid Template:

http://www.wpfsharp.com/2011/05/how-to-disable-row-selection-in-a-wpf-datagrid/

Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? I mean why do you want to forbid a user from selecting a row by clicking it, but yet allow the user to select a row indirectly by using some navigation buttons?

Comment: I'll check this out.  I'm using a DataGrid to display a list of steps that need to happen in a certain order.  As the steps are completed, they will be marked as completed.  I do not want the user to finish the steps in the wrong order.